# PowerShell add spaces at end of line

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with multiple lines and each line needs to be exactly 700 characters long. Below is what I have and for it to work I have to add spaces after $_ until the line is exactly 700 characters long. I'm wondering if there is way where I can specify a number and it uses that to add the number for spaces after each line?

```
get-content test.txt | ForEach-Object {Add-Content output.txt "$_ "}
```

Comment: When I try this it just adds the string <code>  + ' ' * 700 </code> end of each line but doesn't seem to add any whitespaces

Comment: Did you write it like this `$_ + ' ' * 700` or like this `"$_ + ' ' * 700"`?

Comment: I did like "$_ + ' ' * 700"

Comment: You should do it like `$_ + ' ' * 700`. And, BTW, do you want add 700 spaces to the end of line or you want have lines 700 characters long?

Comment: I want the lines to be 700 characters long. The test.txt file has multiple lines that could be 100, 120, 116 characters long. The script should just expand the line to 700.

Answer (score 4):

Based on you question the result will have variable length lines with 700 additional (considering there already maybe spaces at the end) spaces at the end.  Considering strings are immutable this will use a good bit a memory.

You should form you 700 space string and append it to each line.

### Simple Example

```
$700spaces = ' ' * 700
get-content test.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ + $700spaces}
```

### Updated sample based on comment that lines should be exactly 700 characters

```
get-content test.txt | ForEach-Object {Add-Content output.txt ($_ + ' ' * (700 - ($_.Length +1)))}
```

## Reducing memory usage

Using a string builder would be more efficient.  The result of this will be slightly different.  It will be one string with `[environment]::NewLine` between lines.  Where the first will be each line in a separate string.

### string builder example

```
$sb = new-object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
$700spaces = ' ' * 700
get-content test.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $sb.AppendFormat('{0}{1}',$_,$700spaces) > $null
    $sb.AppendLine([String]::empty) > $null
}
$sb.ToString()
```

Comment: The simple example worked but with little modification. Once I assigned a the string to a variable it seems to have worked. get-content test.txt | ForEach-Object {Add-Content output.txt "$_ $700spaces"}. But for some reason the each line didn't end at 700 but at different spaces. Should it just start counting at the end of each line + 700?

Comment: You want each line to be exactly 700 characters long? Added sample assuming this is correct

Comment: Thanks..tried the sample but the lines are not showing exactly as 700 characters.

Comment: How are you counting the characters.  How many characters did each line show up as?

Comment: The text file has multiple lines and each line could have different number of characters. When I run the script each line seems to have different length. Some lines are 767, 781, 788.

Comment: Did you run 'Updated sample based on comment that lines should be exactly 700 characters' or the 'simple sample'.   Since up until your previous response I didn't know the problem you were trying to solve.  I included them both.

Comment: I actually ran the "Updated sample based on comment that lines should be exactly 700 characters". Also I am using Notepad++ to count the characters for each line not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: It's basically an file that we need to provide to someone and there system is expecting 700 characters in a line.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the exactly 700 sample.  I have fixed it now.  Each line is 700 characters, up until the newline.

Comment: Thank you Thank you soo much!! worked like a charm!. Each line was going to 702 for some reason and I just changed the length to 698 and now it shows 700 for each line!!!. Thank you again soo much!

Comment: Just FYI, The extra 2 characters are the Carriage return and line feed.  Which is what windows uses to move to the next line.